# Android how to search in empty query

Tags: android, searchview

I have an search view, below the search view contain edittext. i can check based on search view query and edittext content. Event the query is empty i need to search. Is this is

I have tried this but doesn't work

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Log.i("MyApp", searchView.getQuery().toString());
        consultarListaParadas(searchView.getQuery().toString());
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adaptadorListaParadasBus.setListaParadas(listaParadas);
                adaptadorListaParadasBus.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        if(newText.equals("")){
            this.onQueryTextSubmit("");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can try with TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) instead of newText.equals("")

Answer (score 2):

Try with below condition inside onQueryTextChange() method, like below

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
     // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Good but this works whenever query is empty. How to fire onQueryTextSubmit callback when click submit button(search icon) with empty query ?

Answer (score 1):

*First thing first..*

**`onQueryTextChange()` will not be fired until you are not entering any text**

, Instead what you can do is, make a call to `search` api with empty `query` param and get results...

Once text changes - You can use conditions given in other answers!! **even your condition will work too.**